# the number of comparisons done in std::sort()

Tags: c++, sorting

How can I count the number of comparisons that happens in The standard C++ STL sort function when sorting a vector with n integers?

Comment: You can provide your own function that does the standard comparison and also counts the number of times it is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One quick, non-intrusive way is to use a lambda function. you can use a lambda if you are using C++11 or above, so something like the following:

```
unsigned int numComparisons = 0U;
std::vector<unsigned int> someContainer;
// Fill container, etc.
std::sort( 
    std::begin(someContainer), 
    std::end(someContainer),
    [&numComparisons]( unsigned int lhs, unsigned int rhs ) 
    {
        ++numComparisons;
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
);

std::cout << numComparisons << " comparisons were performed in std::sort" << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note: The observational approach is useful for seeing what's really happening, but it also means you're measuring *your* standard library's `sort` for *your* particular input. If some other standard library decided to, say, adopt the TimSort algorithm from Python, and your input was already mostly/entirely sorted, the adaptive nature of that sort might reduce the comparison work to ~`O(n)`, even though the normal case work would be `O(n log n)`, so your observation would give an observation that's misleading in general. Knowing the documented *guarantees* can be important.

Comment: I completely agree with ShadowRanger and would encourage a reader to also read his answer. It depends somewhat on *why* you are measuring this! As always with profiling, it's important to do it with realistic data and environments.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the observational approach, you can read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). On complexity, `std::sort` must be:

> O(N·log(N)), where N = std::distance(first, last) comparisons on average.
>       (until C++11)
>
> O(N·log(N)), where N = std::distance(first, last) comparisons.
>       (since C++11)

Obviously, big-O notation can mask some constant factors, but in general, expect it to be proportionate to N·log(N) (where the log is base 2, like all good CS logs).

Comment: I dont get the difference between the "until" and "since". Isnt big O upper limits always? So what is the meaning of the "average" (or its absence)?

Comment: @tobi303 The big O notation does describe an upper asymptotic limit as N grows. However, in this case the *order* of the input matters, an algorithm can be O(N log(N)) when averaging over the possible orderings but have destructive cases with O(N^2) for instance. The C++11 limit is tighter and specifies O(N log(N)) for all possible input orderings.

Comment: @ThomasRussell thx, I will have to think about it for a moment.

Comment: btw the difference between log2(x) and log10(x) is just a constant factor, so it doesnt really matter whether it is the "good CS log" or not ;)

Comment: @tobi303: True. Indicating it's log2 does remind you that the cost is higher than log10 before other constant factors get involved, but yes, the difference is a constant factor of ~3.32, so the base can be ignored.

Comment: @ThomasRussell I think it got it. So depeding on my input "O(N logN) on average" can be arbitrarily worse than O(N logN) for a single case. Good to know that it was improved :)